# can I define browserlist into .browserlistrc for next.js?

Tags: next.js

nextjs documentation says I should define my browserlist into the `package.json`.
I'd prefer using the `.browserlintrc` file but I'm not that sure it's fully supported.

Documentation page:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features#browserslist